# Violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, content-security-policy

When I upload an image into my web application, it is showing the below error

> Refused to load the image ' `<URL>` because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I try to solve this error by using the following code

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src * 'self' data: https:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

But it is not working. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are using an "*". I am using a similar kind of stuff, but my meta tag looks something like this and it works fine for me:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; connect-src 'self';font-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: https:; style-src 'self' ; script-src 'self'">
```