# Loading favicon icon from Express web server causes Content-Security-Policy violation

Tags: node.js, express, favicon, content-security-policy

I get the following error when I try to load the website I am creating

> Refused to load the image 'http://167.71.89.74/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

It looks like my attempts to fix the error change the X-Content-Security-Policy, but not the Content-Security-Policy.

I am using a simple Express server to load the page requests.

I found this question and added a meta tag to my Index.html, but that didn't fix the error.

[violates the following Content Security Policy directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369507/violates-the-following-content-security-policy-directive)

Here is the meta tag I added

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'">
```

I also tried changing my Express code to do a setHeader as described in the answer to this question

[nodeJS https - unable to set Content-Security-Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52291783/nodejs-https-unable-to-set-content-security-policy)

Here is my setHeader code

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';");
  return next();
});
```

I then found out about [Helmet](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/csp/) which has a module that allows you to set content security policy.  Here is my Helmet code

```
const csp = require('helmet-csp');

app.use(csp({
  directives: {
    defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
    scriptSrc: ["'self'"],
    connectSrc: ["'self'"],
    imgSrc: ["'self'"],
    styleSrc: ["'self'"]
  }
}));
```

When I run the following curl command

```
curl http://167.71.89.74/ --include
```

I get this

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'
X-WebKit-CSP: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 139
Date: Fri, 09 Aug 2019 19:53:14 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

It looks like my code is setting the X-Content-Security-Policy, but not the Content-Security-Policy.

To fix my error, do I need to make some other change to set the Content-Security-Policy in addition to the X-Content-Security-Policy?

Comment: Not familiar with Node or Helmet, but I can tell you that when a CSP policy is set, you can't later add something that loosens the policy. (You can tighten the rules, but not loosen them.)  So once that `default-src 'none';` is set, adding the proper CSP later doesn't change anything because the initial setting takes precedence.

Comment: @StephenR Any idea how to change the initial setting?  I tried setting the initial setting in my Express code when doing the setHeader call and then I tried using Helmet, but neither worked.

Comment: As I said, I’m not familiar with Node or Helmet, so No. Sorry.  Dig in to however Node sets defaults...?